# Start/stop postgresql with pg_ctl or service without root access on RHEL6

Tags: postgresql, redhat, startup, automation

We plan to use postgresql on RHEL 6.

DBAs won't have root access but they will need to start/stop the databases.
They'll be able to do so with `pg_ctl` as postgres.

However databases should also start automatically when the server reboots and so we should use services (`/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.x`).

When postgres is started with service (as root) and stopped with pg_ctl as postgres, the pid file in `$PGDATA` is deleted but not the specific pid and lock files (respectively in `/var/run` and `/var/lock/subsys`) created by the init.d script.

It leads to an inconsistent state where `service postgresql-9.x status` throws"postgresql-9.x dead but pid file exists".

So what is the best practice and solution for this situation?

- ask sysadmin to give `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.x` to the DBAs and never use pg_ctl again?
- remove the specific pid and lock files from the postgresql-9.x service script?
- any other idea?